# Prevent double tap zoom without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

In latest iOS Safari, unexpected double tap zoom cannot prevent, so my full-screen map application sometimes lost control of users.

I found the solution with jQuery, it works well.

```
$.fn.nodoubletapzoom = function() {
    $(this).bind('touchstart', function preventZoom(e) {
        var t2 = e.timeStamp;
        var t1 = $(this).data('lastTouch') || t2;
        var dt = t2 - t1;
        var fingers = e.originalEvent.touches.length;
        $(this).data('lastTouch', t2);
        if (!dt || dt > 500 || fingers > 1) {
            return; // not double-tap
        }
        e.preventDefault(); // double tap - prevent the zoom
        // also synthesize click events we just swallowed up
        $(e.target).trigger('click');
    });
};
$('body').nodoubletapzoom();
```

But I want to do this without jQuery.

What is the equivalent to this code without jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function() {
    var lastTouch = 0;
    function preventZoom(e) {
        var t2 = e.timeStamp;
        var t1 = lastTouch || t2;
        var dt = t2 - t1;
        var fingers = e.touches.length;
        lastTouch = t2;

        if (!dt || dt >= 300 || fingers > 1) {
            return;
        }
        resetPreventZoom();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.click();
    }
    function resetPreventZoom() {
        lastTouch = 0;
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', preventZoom, false);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', resetPreventZoom, false);
})();
```

**EDIT:** I have improved by listening to touchmove, when I reset touch interval, because it can harm rapid scrolling. Also I made delay 300 ms, because this is commonly used delay on touchscreens. 500 ms delay is too long.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: I may be wrong on this; however, it is from my understanding that since iOS 10 this feature only is applicable to web apps. I don't believe it is functional on Safari Mobile.

Comment: ahhh -- yes just tested it -- doesn't work on safari mobile --

Answer (score 0):

this should work -- add to css

```
html,body{user-zoom:fixed;}
```